# is it impossible to know a Wifi mac address of an android phone via a link?

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, chrome-for-android, gps-tracking, mac-address

There is someone that I doubt that he uses my stolen phone so I want to make sure that the phone that he uses is mine or not by knowing the Wifi mac address of phone – to see if it's mine or not.

I have used [iplogger](http://iplogger.org) before but all what it shows is ip address- Android  version - browser - phone model-etc. I just wanna make sure before telling telling the police about this person.

I have already done tracking report, but they did nothing.

What can I do ?? The phone uses Android 5.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IP logger captures the IP address and the browser user agent string, the browser user agent only contains information like phone model and browser, no uniquely identifying information like MAC addresses.

So no, this iplogger (or any other that uses similar techniques) cannot determine if the phone is actually your's, only if it is the same model, but thousands of that model are sold so that is not considered evidence.

Comment: is there anything can capture a mac address similar to IP logger ?

Comment: @minanageh No, the only way to obtain someone's mac address is to either be on the same network, or looking it up in their phone's info tab in the settings.

Comment: OK thanks .. I will try my lucky at IP logger ..

Answer (score 0):

What you'd need for that is something that also supports [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol). You could try a tool like [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing), which does that:

[image: Fing] [image: Fing]
<sup>Fing (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As you can see in the second screenshot, *Fing* is able to tell the MAC address (at least of nearby devices). Some alternative apps [can be found in my corresponding list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis#group_374).

Comment: this not what i mean ... he is not in the same network as me

Comment: Then you are very much out of look – see [How to get MAC address via IP](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/64281/90974) at our security sister-site.

Comment: didn't help .. that's ok